# Get path to Portable Device in Vista

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista

I'm trying to write a quick app to fix the ID3 tags on my MP3 player, and I hit an annoying snag. When I plug my MP3 player into the USB, it shows up in Vista under the Portable Devices category and doesn't get a drive letter assigned. I'm using Vista x64 Home Premium and .NET 3.5.

The path looks something like "Computer\MP3 Device"

Trying to just use that path doesn't work, and from what I saw, there's no SpecialFolder that points to where I'm trying to get. I've tried opening up Disk Management and assigning a drive letter, but the Portable Device doesn't show up.

I pretty much just want to be able to do a Directory.GetFiles(...). Is there a way to get the path that will let me do that? Has anyone else encountered something like this in Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't present as a mass storage device, then it won't be mapped into the file system.